# programmatically email with attached image in Android

Tags: android

I want to mail programmatically in Android and I also want to attach an image which is stored in drawable..Is this possible? if yes how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding image in email in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148486/embedding-image-in-email-in-android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application

also, cant you just use javamail api?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/index-138643.html