# Image not displayed

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, html-email

I am using mail composer in andorid and trying to send html data as below using intent:

```
 String body = "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body> " +
            "<img src = \"http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/images/atitlan.jpg\" >" +
            "</body> " +
            "</html> ";
    final Intent shareIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

    shareIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
    shareIntent2.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml(body)
    );
    startActivity(shareIntent2);
```

But, Image does not displaying in message body.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: did you tried without `Html.fromHtml(body)` ?

Comment: try only `body` not `Html.fromHtml(body)`

Comment: How can we do without Html.fromHtml(body) ?

Comment: I have tried without it, But, It displaying html code in message body instead of image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-to-add-an-image-in-email-body

Comment: have a look in the link

Comment: one thing you can try is to set the type to `intent.setType("text/html");`.
see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148926/3790052

Comment: @sourabhbans not working...

Comment: Ohhh... last try on this.. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/how-to/2008/08/embedding-images-in-email/ after this i couldn't..