# android sharing a text file facebook, twitter, email

Tags: android, facebook, file, twitter, text-files

I need to share a text file (created in my app and stored on the sd card) by using facebook, twitter, email at least.
My question is what would be the easiest way to do this? I need to know where to focus. I have installed the facebook sdk, but still cannot get how to use it to send a txt file. 
I will be grateful for any general guidance.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a file to an email as an attachment: [Trying to attach a file from SD Card to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email)
2. AFAIK Facebook does not allow you to share files. You can post text and images, but not files in general.
3. Twitter same as 2. above. You can post tweets - text up to 140 chars long. You can also post pictures via TwitPic. But you cant share files in general.

You could upload a file to some file sharing site (you'd need account for that) and then share url via Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I wonder then if I could 'copy' the content of my text file into the text field for facebook or twitter so the user would send it.