# Sharing image Only Works For Facebook but not twitter or email

Tags: android

I implemented share code that looks like anything else found when you search on StackOverflow.

```
String pathToExportedFile = getPath();

// Export for share
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
  Uri.parse("file:///" + pathToExportedFile));

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "See Attachment");

model.activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select a way to Share"));
```

However, it only works for Facebook. When I choose gmail, it looks like it is attached but when I recepient of the email gets no attachment. When I do it through Twitter, it says it cannot find the attachment.

The image file that is attached resides in "sdcard\DCIM\Camera"

Please help,

-mL

Update:

My file path is good but it looks like gmail is garbage collecting it? Here are some select ADB logs:

```
02-01 16:36:46.720: D/Gmail(1896): Cached file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1328132065637.jpg to /data/data/com.google.android.gm/cache/2012-02-01-16:36:46428133821.attachment
02-01 16:36:46.880: D/Gmail(1896): MailProvider.insert(): added local message 140
02-01 16:36:47.100: I/Gmail(1896): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 554429, normalSync: true
02-01 16:36:49.900: I/Gmail(1896): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 554462, normalSync: true
02-01 16:36:51.650: D/Gmail(1896): Cleaning up cached attachment: /data/data/com.google.android.gm/cache/2012-02-01-16:36:46428133821.attachment
02-01 16:36:51.650: D/Gmail(1896): Updating message 1392647555039793989. synced=true
02-01 16:36:52.230: I/Gmail(1896): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 554477, normalSync: true
```

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: I have not ever seen that twitter is allowing to share image. As it post tweets only. But you can add a URL of image

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [Trying to attach a file from SD Card to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email)

Also getting the same problem
(...)

From adb logcat:

```
V/DumbDumpersMain( 3972):   sPhotoUri=file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.CHOOSER comp={android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x3000000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail} (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x2800000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivity} (has extras) }
D/gmail-ls(  120):      MailProvider.query: content://gmail-ls/labels/me@gmail.com(null, null)
D/Gmail   ( 2507):      URI FOUND:file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
```

Looks like the email provider is attaching a 0 length file.  When I check the filesystem the file is there and correct.  The code which creates the image file is well finished prior to the attempt to email it.

(...)

**Update**

Path for me should have been

`file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg`

you need the extra `/` as this points to the root directory, i.e.:

`file://` **+** `/sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg`

combined as

`file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg`

In the above snippet you need:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+ sPhotoFileName));
```

I hope this helps. It took me ages to debug.

Regards,
Finlay

Comment: Can you try: uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILENAME)); instead of using "file:///"