# Attach an XLS (Excel) file to Email

Tags: android, email, attachment, excellibrary

My application uses the **intent** method to send out emails to users, as a convenient way of exporting Excel spreadsheet data (created by the [JExcell API](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/)).

The file is contained on the SD card in a folder called **records**.

The file I am attempting to send is call **measurments.xls.**

I have tested in code for the existence of the file prior to sending. The email composer shows an attachment, but when I send and then receive the email the attachment is not there.

However, if I substitute the excel file for a png image, the attachment is received. So what gives??

Below is the code I use to send out the email, it is simply a paramiterised static method in a class by its self.

```
    public static  void sendEmailWithAttachment(Context ctx, String to,String subject, String message, String fileAndLocation)
    {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {to}); 

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  message); 


          File file = new File(fileAndLocation);
         //  File file = getFileStreamPath();
           if (file.exists())
           {
               Log.v("Farmgraze", "Email file_exists!" );
           }
           else
           {
               Log.v("Farmgraze", "Email file does not exist!" );
           }


        Log.v("FarmGraze", "SEND EMAIL FileUri=" + Uri.parse("file:/"+ fileAndLocation));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+  fileAndLocation));

        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }//end method
```

So what do I need to do to receive the xls file? Change the mime types in the second line of the method's code? If so what do. Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

```
A.
```

Comment: Are you sure the outgoing/incoming mail server does not strip certain attachments? Try sending it to/from a gmail account. I suppose that changing the MIME type could help, but it is more likely the mail server.

Comment: Hmm, no idea if it makes a difference but I normally see the `file:/` with two slashes `file://`. Try it out.

Comment: @Chuck Norris I have send the file via GMail web app, to my work email and the file got through so we can rule that out.

Comment: @Gophermofur I have one slash because the fileAndLocation String contains the other as its first character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok folks just to add closure to this question I found the solution.

The problem was that the file path String sent to the URI, needs to have three forward slashes.

As in:

```
file:///sdcard/somefolder/some_file.xls.
```

Also for excel documents one needs to set the type as follows:

```
emailIntent.setType("application/excel");
```

So the problem was a two pronged one. I was aware of the three slash solution via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email), but as it did not work thought the problem lie else where.

Also I became aware of the correct mime types via [this webpage](http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/iis/mimetypes) which lists all of the supported mime types, and may be very useful for other readers.

So thanks for reading and taking an interest in my little problem which is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with your mime-type. Try this:

```
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();     
String mimeTypeForXLSFile = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(".xls");

emailIntent.setType(mimeTypeForXLSFile);
```

Comment: Thank for suggesting this but, I get  a 'Send Mail'  dialog stating 'No Applications can perform this action'.

Comment: On the emulator or on your phone? I get that message when I try it on the emulator, but it works fine on a phone.

Comment: On a phone, a Galaxy S2 and a Galaxy Ace running 2.3.3