# How to access an image that is stored internally

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

I have an application that takes a picture and stores the picture internally in a folder that I have created. After taking a picture I want to be able to access it so that I can email it. How can I access the image I have just taken?Below is my code that saves the image internally after the picture has been taken:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        File storagePath = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DavePics/");
        storagePath.mkdirs();

        File myImage = new File(storagePath, Long.toString(System
                .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");


        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 320, 480, false);

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

When I check the folder I have created the picture is there. What I want to do now is access that picture so that I can send it in an email from my code below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSendPic:

        String emailaddress[] = { "info@sklep.com", "", };

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);

        //emailIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pic);

        emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));

        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:

        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }

}
```

How do I access this pic so that I can add it to my email intent? Am i going about this the right way? Thanks

Edit: This is my full code

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bmp;
File myImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

}

private void initialize() {
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendPic);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSendPic:

        if (myImage.exists()) {

            String emailaddress[] = { "info@sklep.com", "", };

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
            emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            emailIntent
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myImage));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));

        }

        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:

        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        File storagePath = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DavePics/");
        storagePath.mkdirs();

        myImage = new File(storagePath, Long.toString(System
                .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 320, 480, false);

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code line you forgot is,,

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myImage));
```

In your code, declare `File myImage` globally in your activity,

Now at Email send code

check whether file is exist or not,

```
if(myImage.exist())
{
 String emailaddress[] = { "info@sklep.com", "", };
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
 emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myImage));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did this and when I go to send the email you can see that the attachment has been added. However when i send the email it just says email sending and then it never sends. I have attahced my full code. Any ideas?

Comment: I know have this working. Thanks a million! My gmail account kept freezing but once I cleared the cache and restarted it then it worked perfectly!