# Content-Type for sending E-Mail does not work

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm trying to send E-Mail from an Android App using the Intent.

I'm using the following code:

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.emailText));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MyBackup");
    email.setType("application/zip");
    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + this.tmpFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, getString(R.string.strSendEMail)));
```

The code works, and I receive the E-Mail, but the ZIP-file is in the E-Mail as "plain/text"...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different mimetype:

```
email.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work... The ZIP-file is always: [MyBackup.zip  text/plain (15452 Bytes)]

Comment: Have you tried using Uri.fromFile instead? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email

Answer (score 0):

I just tried sending an E-Mail with a ZIP attached. Not from my program, but directly from the E-Mail-Program of my phone.
Same result. Well, I think, the problem ist **not** in my program, but in the E-Mail-Program...

Thanks a lot again for your help. I think, I have to search a better program to send E-Mails...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Bro I was stuck too with same issue, used following code before prepration of message and calling send mail method. just add following piece of code.

```
     Message message = createMessage(toEmail, subject, messageBody, session);
            MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
            mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
            mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
            mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
            mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
            mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
// Additional elements to make DSN work
            mc.addMailcap("multipart/report;;  x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.dsn.multipart_report");
            mc.addMailcap("message/delivery-status;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.dsn.message_deliverystatus");
            mc.addMailcap("message/disposition-notification;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.dsn.message_dispositionnotification");
            mc.addMailcap("text/rfc822-headers;;   x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.dsn.text_rfc822headers");
            new SendEmail(message).execute();
```

I found this answer in a different thread please try and let me know if it helps you.