# how to attach a jpeg file to mail in android?

Tags: android

i will attach the file but they show as a (0 bytes)
below code is i used

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ToDoNot.es");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(message));
File save_Image;
File temp=null;
save_Image=new File(ToDoViewActivity.this.getFilesDir(),"todofile");
temp=new File(save_Image,"tempfile"+String.valueOf(values.getAsInteger("rowid"))+".jpg");
Uri U = Uri.fromFile(new File("file://"+temp.getPath()));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,U);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

outpur:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue too - the problem is that you're trying to attach a file from your app's internal files directory, and the email intent doesn't have permissions to access it.

Copy it to the "external" storage first, then attach it to the email.  That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't type the file type... maybe it's becoz of this.

```
save_Image=new File(.........................."todofile.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related with the **getPath** call on the **temp** file. Check the return value of that call, and make sure that the constructed URI that you are passing to **putExtra** matches one of the styles described in these documents:

[Trying to attach a file from SD Card to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email)

https://superuser.com/questions/352133/what-is-the-reason-that-file-urls-start-with-three-slashes-file-etc

Most notably, you need 3 slashes after *file:*. Also, but unlikely, your issue may be caused by the MIME type you are setting with **setType**.