# Attaching file in android

Tags: android, android-intent

How could I attach a file using Intent.ACTION_SENDTO...I used the following code but the file is not attached....I read in some posts that it is not possible

```
Uri mail= Uri.fromParts("mailto",message, null);                         

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mail);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mailcontent);                
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Folder/abc.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following link: [Trying to attach a file from SD Card to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email) It seems that they got this working after much debugging. So your question may have already been answered.

Comment: I had already gone through that link and tried them.But it just won't get attached.I tried the same using Action_Send and it attaches the file...Wonder what's the problem with Action_Sendto

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
File tmpDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temp/");
File tmpFile = new File(tmpDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + attachedFile.getName());
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

I think the `Uri.fromFile()` part may be the key here, or prepending the `file://` bit.

Comment: -I guess you are trying to attach file hat are not in /sdcard...btw i tried Uri.fromFile() as well...Unfortunately it didn't help